# NodeJS spawned process works on Mac, fails on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, vagrant

I'm spawning a process from node to run vagrant ssh commands on a VM. This works on Mac, but fails on windows with the following error:

> grep: no such file or directory

Code:

```
'use strict'
const spawn = require('cross-spawn')
const vagrantOptions = { cwd: `${__dirname}/../../vagrant/`, stdio: 'inherit' }
// this line works
spawn.sync('vagrant', ['ssh', 'xms-dev', '-c', 'sudo service supervisor stop'], vagrantOptions))

// this line doesn't work on Windows
spawn.sync('vagrant', ['ssh', 'xms-dev', '-c', 'sudo service supervisor status | grep -q "not running"; until [ $? -eq 0 ]; do sleep 1; sudo service supervisor status | grep -q "not running"; done'], vagrantOptions))
```

If I run the process myself on Windows, it works as expected.

Comment: NodeJs + Windows = MAX_PATH failure!  Windows FAT supports long directory names but some of the OS features used by Node modules don't.  That could be why.

Comment: Current versions of Node (NPM really) don't have the node_modules path explosion issues of the past. That isn't the issue here - the process starts, but what is run on the ubuntu VM is just not working.